# Struggling installing Jekyll on El Capitan

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rbenv

I'm having issues getting Jekyll working on El Capitan. Well, any Gem really. All my Gem installs failed, and I found out it was because of Apple's System Integrity Protection, and the recommended solution is to use ruby versioning tool RBENV.

- Installed `rbenv` and `ruby-build` using homebrow
- Installed Ruby 2.3.0
- Set `rbenv global` to 2.3.0
- ran `rbenv init` and added it to `~/.zshenv` so my path now looks like: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/thuijls/.rbenv/shims`
- `gem install` works fine, I installed jekyll and some other gems. No drama, everything installed to `/usr/local/bin/gems`.
- ran `rbenv rehash`

Running **any** of them tho:

```
/usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.3/bin/jekyll (LoadError)
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

They still try to access Apple's standard Ruby in `/Library/`, which is where none of those Gems are installed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't use rbenv, try these few steps:

- run `brew prune` to fix the system's symlinks;
- fix any other issues indicated by `brew doctor`;
- use `.bash_profile` in your home folder instead of `~/.zshenv`

If it still doesn't work, try using RVM:

- install it with an argument to set up your PATH properly with: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles`
- set RVM to use Homebrew to install any necessary dependencies with `rvm autolibs enable && rvm autolibs packages && rvm autolibs homebrew`
- install ruby-2.3.0: `rvm install 2.3.0`
- go ahead and install any gem on your current gemset